# Firebase security hashing UID doesn't match client computed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Following firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#october_8_2019), I have implemented the following security rule:

```
match /docs/{hashID} {
  allow read, write: if hashing.md5(request.auth.uid.toUtf8()).toBase64() == hashID;
}
```

On the client side, I am using [node-md5](https://github.com/pvorb/node-md5) to compute user's hashID and write to a document

```
firebase.firestore().collection("docs").doc(md5(user.uid)).writeSomething()
```

It is failing the security rule because the hashes don't match.

For uid "crz6KyreRCM4A0Qvk9EfeXHBLF43", my client md5 gives me "eee1f958a8c0a273f138bdee0167693d", while Firebase Rules Playground gives me "fbOLeadWz7YxnsGgfESBNg==". I've verified the client md5 value is correct using https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/. What am I doing wrong in the security rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The `node-md5` output was a hex string, so the following rule is appropriate:

```
match /docs/{hashID} {
  allow read, write: if hashing.md5(request.auth.uid.toUtf8()).toHexString() == hashID;
}
```

Furthermore, Firebase's `toHexString()` returns a result in all caps, so I need to do this on the client side

```
firebase.firestore().collection("docs").doc(md5(user.uid).toUpperCase()).writeSomething()
```

Comment: Alternatively we can do `btoa(md5(user.uid, {asString: true}))` on the client side for the base64 rule to work

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `toBase64()` unnecessarily.  That's for converting byte arrays into strings, which can then be hashed.  Since you're dealing entirely with strings here, there is no need to base64 encode anything.

Comment: My hashID is a string while `hashing.md5` returns Bytes. When I take out `toBase64`, I get the error: The sub-expressions are not comparable, so this comparison will always return false. I also tried `toHexString()` but that gives me yet another value that doesn't match.

Comment: Perhaps you want to call [toUtf8()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#toUtf8) on the `hashID` string instead?

Comment: No luck. I'm wondering if I'm giving the same input to node-md5 and hashing.md5. I don't have a way to see the intermediate value of `request.auth.uid.toUtf8()`

Comment: Ah! I had a typo for my uid in Rules Playground! After I fixed that it was straightforward to fix the rest. Will post the answer shortly